# How do you format data so that it can be easily consumed by MV* frameworks like Angular, Backbone, Ember, etc.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, angularjs, backbone.js

I'm asking this question to fill a hole in my knowledge, myself having historically been primarily a front-end developer with little concern for server-side code for the longest time. I basically need some way to structure my data so that all relevant information from multiple tables in my database all exist in one place. So, let's say I have a user profile page for a Rails-based site that will use Angular.js on the client. My Angular code might expect a data model like this:

```
var user = {
  "first_name": "Arkady",
  "last_name": "Dracul",
  "courses": [
    {
       "name": "Intro to Chemistry",
       "id": "CH101",
    },
    {
       "name": "Intro to Computer Science",
       "id": "CS101",
    },
    {
       "name": "Intro to Whatever",
       "id": "W101",
    }
  ],
  "clubs": [
    {
      "name": "Salsa",
      "id": "SDA"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tango",
      "id": "TDA"
    }
  ]
}
```

How on earth do I actually get the data from the various tables in my database to come out structured like this? Mind you, I'm guessing (!) that I may need to have different data models for different views but am uncertain as to whether that would be a good practice if two views are mostly similar. Really, I'm not sure how to go about structuring data for consumption by the front end. Apart from any answers you provide here, are there any books that provide useful beginner-/intermediate-level information for someone like myself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you are on rails, you can use a `someUser.to_json` to convert your database object to json.

Beside this, if you are trying to implement an API with rails, I strongly recommend grape https://github.com/intridea/grape. It is in active development, and I love it!

You also can build JSON views along with grape using Rabl https://github.com/nesquena/rabl or json_builder https://github.com/dewski/json_builder